# Question in Linear response theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, microscopy

I am currently trying to do a calculation using linear response, but I am confused on one thing I never thought of. To start here is the relevant equation (I assumed the operators are self evident to anyone able to answer this question):
$$\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \delta \langle \hat{O}(\mathbf{x},t)\rangle
    =
    -i
    \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}
    dt'
    \theta(t-t')
    \langle{G|\big[
    \hat{O}^I(\mathbf{x},t),
    \hat{\mathcal{H}}^I_{int}(t')
    \big]
    |G}
    \rangle
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*} $$
The RHS starts in the interaction picture, but we expand the time evolution operator acting on $|G\rangle$ out, and keep linear order terms, which is where the commutator comes from. This means the ket on the RHS does not time evolve, so it basically belongs to the Heisenberg representation. This seems weird to me since we have a mixture of operators and kets from different pictures on the RHS.

Should these all be put in the same picture to make sense? Furthermore, I have seen this formula somewhat hand-wavingly be recast purely into the Heisenberg picture (the operators have H's as superscripts). Is this even possible in general? This step seems necessary to replace the averages with correlation functions, but I find myself being unsure... Any help on how this can be done, or if it can/can not be done in general is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I think. Since $|G\rangle$ is the ground state of $\hat{H}_0$ the bare Hamiltonian, and the operators in the interaction picture evolve according to $\hat{H}_0$, the expectation value is a Green function in the Heisenberg picture after all! No mixing of pictures really, and this makes sense because unperturbed Green functions are used to calculate the effects of perturbations.